# Single template for multiple locales

Tags: localization, templating

How can I avoid local specific templates? I'd like just to use one template for all languages.

My current template structure is extending layouts/_base, and layout/_site [similar to happylager demo] and I have a template called 'help' but i dont want to set 'fr/help', 'es/help'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to use sections / entries for ALL of your templates. This not only allows to automatically route each local's page URL to a single template, it also makes it possible to set local specific slugs for each entry. You might not care for translated URLs, but Google does.

So what I recommend is to restructure your setup a bit, add a bunch of singles or even better, a structure named "pages", and set the path to your templates in the section settings.

Comment: Do you mean i cant use a single template for locales if I am extending from a base? Section is specifying only one template. "help" is section name/handle. Template is "help/_entry"

Comment: Not sure I can follow your first sentence, what do you mean with *"extending from a base"*.

Comment: *"Section is specifying only one template"* – that's how it should work. You point all of this section's entry requests (any locale !!) to that template, isn't this what you're after? All locales, one template?